# strong equivalent metrics

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_x),(Y,d_Y)$ be bounded metric space. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a homeomorphism. Is it true that there exist $a,b>0$ such that
$$ad_X(x_1,x_2)<d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))<bd_X(x_1,x_2)$$
for any $x_1,x_2\in X$?

Comment: Think of the map $y=x^2$ of the unit interval.

Answer (score 0):

The maps with the property you described are called *bi-Lipschitz* homeomorphisms. This is a strictly stronger property than being a homeomorphism. Two concrete examples are $f(x)=x^2$ on $[0,1]$ and its inverse (taken from comment by studiosus). A more abstract example: let $(X,d)$ be any metric space, and consider the identity map from $(X,d)$ to $(X,d^{1/2})$. Here   $d^{1/2}$ means the metric $\sqrt{d(x,y)}$ on the same set. Unless $X$ is a discrete space, $f$ is not Lipschitz.